# How to decode this php file

Tags: decode

I want to decode this PHP code. I have no idea what it is, except that it is some kind of code. Can someone help me please?
onecompiler :

```
https://onecompiler.com/php/3x5as9wq4
```

Comment: Let's parse the code in the following _naive_  manner: `$_VBUYNG="\142\141\163\x65\x36\64\137\144\145\x63\157\x64\145"` at the 14th line means `base64_decode`. Then _do not run_ the following [`eval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php); get its argument instead, i.e. result of [`base64_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php). You get something similar to initial code. Do the same procedure on it; after five iterations you have decoded PHP, if you retain non-encoded parts…

Comment: I did
But I could not decode